Spring Cloud Stream aggregator-function Bean Binding issue while using with Spring Boot 3, Java 21
we have a kafka stream application based on spring boot kafka binder on spring boot 2.6.8, Java 8 that uses AggregatorFunctionConfiguration as below (Spring cloud version 2021.0.0)
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(AggregatorFunctionConfiguration.class)
public class AggregatorProcessorKafkaApplication {


The version of function dependencies is 1.2.1
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud.fn</groupId>
            <artifactId>aggregator-function</artifactId>
        </dependency>

But the same application on upgrading to Spring boot 3.2.x and Java 21, spring cloud version 2023.0.0 based on our organization needs to upgrade apps, we are running into an issue with bean instantiation issues similar to below
Parameter 0 of method aggregatorFunction in org.springframework.cloud.fn.aggregator.AggregatorFunctionConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - inputChannel: defined by method 'inputChannel' in org.springframework.cloud.fn.aggregator.AggregatorFunctionConfiguration
    - outputChannel: defined by method 'outputChannel' in org.springframework.cloud.fn.aggregator.AggregatorFunctionConfiguration

Is there a aggregation function that is compatible with java 21, (tried with version 4.0.0) that we can use, or what is the latest java and boot version that we can upgrade to when using aggregator function 4.0.0
